# Gatsby Not Resolving GraphQL Image Address

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

My project is based on the [gatsby-creative](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/JohnJKerr/gatsby-creative/) starter.  I am trying to add an Open Graph image meta property.  Unfortunately, the address of the image in the source folder is not being translated into a proper content path.  Here is what I did...

I started by adding a "url" and "image" properties to siteMetaData:

```
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `A Web Site`,
    description: `Yes, this is a web site.`,
    author: `Brent Arias`,
    url: `https://website.com`,
    image: `/images/snape.jpg`
  },
```

So far I'm doing the same thing as the [online documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/add-seo-component/).  However, those instructions have a comment which states the above "image" property contains the `Path to your image you placed in the 'static' folder`.  Huh?  I don't believe I'm supposed to "place an image in the static folder"...I think that is Gatsby's job.  But moving along...

Starting from this original [seo.js file](https://github.com/JohnJKerr/gatsby-creative/blob/master/src/components/seo.js), I added the same "url" and "image" properties to the graphQL query:

```
  const { site } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            description
            author
            url
            image
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )
```

Seemingly, so far so good.  Finally, in the same seo.js file, I added an entry for the image itself:

```
        {
          property: `og:type`,
          content: `website`,
        },
        {
          property: `og:url`,
          content: site.siteMetadata.url,
        },
        {
          property: `og:image`,
          content: `${site.siteMetadata.url}${site.siteMetadata.image}`
        },
```

When the page renders, the meta tag contains the useless address `https://website.com/images/snape.jpg`.

Yes the [online documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/add-seo-component/) is not identical to this approach, but it seems to be the equivalent.  I don't see why the address isn't being resolved to the "static" folder where the image should be found.

As a work-around hack, instead I added to the seo.js file the following:

`import socialBanner from '../images/snape.jpg'`

When I place that `socialBanner` into the "content" of that same "og:image" property, then it works as expected and resolves to: `https://website.com/static/snape-119744a51329473845d08af3df4b5290.jpg`.

I don't want that hack. What do I need to change to properly make use of Gatsby tools (StaticQuery, Helmet, etc) to handle this image and address?

Comment: I don't understand what you're wanting or not wanting. The contents of the `static` folder are copied over to `public` at build time. This allows you to reference local content that isn't handled by webpack. If you would prefer to have webpack do something with your static image then you can import it as you've shown, but you're including it in a bundle needlessly.

Comment: @coreyward I want to point to an image in my `images` folder, then auto-processed into my static folder (just like the online documentation).  My folder structure is what the gatsby starter gave me.  There is a `static` folder under the `public` folder.  The public folder is excluded from `.gitignore`.  Other images in the solution come from `.\src\images` (having contents captured by git).  I'm trying to follow that pattern.  Likewise the online documentation shows `siteMetaData` pointing to the `images` folder.  Gatsby should translate the indicated image into the static folder for me.

Comment: It is possible to have gatsby transform the image and use graphql to include it within SEO, but it is probably best to create a new `static` folder at root and store your image there. https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-folder/

Comment: @BrentArias Ahhh, you need to use GraphQL to fetch the image if you want that, but if you're not doing any resizing or processing on it it's unnecessary for what you're doing.

Comment: @coreyward The [online documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/add-seo-component/) shows nothing but `siteMetaData` with an `image` property pointing to `/images/snape.jpg`, and the corresponding StaticQuery/Helmet result is a relative path pointing to the `static` folder.  Why does that magic happen for the documentation, but does not happen for me?

Comment: @BrentArias It tells you to put the image in the `static` folder at the root of your project, which is what we explained above. The contents of that will be copied to `public` (not `public/static`) on build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `static` folder being referenced by the Gatsby documentation is at the root of your project. [Here's the documentation for the static folder and it's behavior in Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-folder/).

If you want to use the approach shown in the SEO example documentation, you'll need to add your OpenGraph image to this folder, **not** to `public/static`, which is a folder that Gatsby uses for files that it generates.

> ### Adding assets outside of the module system
>
> You can create a folder named `static` at the root of your project. Every file you put into that folder will be copied into the public folder. E.g. if you add a file named `sun.jpg` to the static folder, it’ll be copied to `public/sun.jpg`

Comment: If I put the image into the `static` folder, true, it will get copied for me.  But the online documentation shows how the meta-tag path for that image is constructed using the code `${siteUrl}${image || defaultImage}`.  That same code, for me, results in `https://example.com/images/snape.jpg` which is a useless path.  How did the that code from online documentation magically produce the correct path `https://example.com/static/snape.jpg`?

Comment: The line-comment spells this out: the `image` property in your siteMetadata should be the “Path to your image you placed in the 'static' folder”. I.e. if you place the image at `static/statis/snape.jpg` you would set `image` to `statis/snape.jpg`.

Comment: @BrentArias The correct URL output *should not* have `static` in it.

Comment: GROAN!  Ok, now I get it!  I can't thank you enough for your patience leading me through this!